# mvc - generating report - selecting ALL datatable items in dataset using dropdown select

Tags: sql, select, model-view-controller, dataset

**this is my controller:**

```
public ActionResult GenerateReport(string Employeename, int year)
{
    EmployeeLeave ds = new EmployeeLeave();
    EmployeeLeaveTableAdapter da = new EmployeeLeaveTableAdapter();
    da.Fill(ds._EmployeeLeave, Employeename, year);
    ....
}
```

**this is the code snippet in my index.cshtml:**

```
<form action="/Report/GenerateReport/" method="post">
    <select id="Employeename" name="Employeename" class="form-control form-    control-lg">
                    <option value="" disabled selected>Select Name</option>
                    <option value="ALL">ALL</option>
                    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.userlist)
                    {
                        <option value="@item.username">@item.lastname</option>
                    }
                </select>

                <select id="year" name="year" class="form-control form-control-lg">
                    <option value="2016">2016</option>
                    <option value="2017">2017</option>
                </select>
                <button type="submit" value="Generate Report" class="btn btn-primary">Generate Report</button>
            </form>
```

and this is the **sql statement** snippet in my dataset table adapter:

```
WHERE        (tblfile_leave.EMP_NAME = @username AND tblfile_leave.YEAR = @year)
```

it gets whatever the value that is in the select option. however, when i select "ALL" in the dropdown, i'm getting no results at all. how can i display all the result in the select statement in connection to the dropdown option "ALL"

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing integer type to your controller function, it will generate javascript error on selecting Select All option as it has value = All which is a string not an integer. You can see this using some browser tools on console window.

One solution is to render option tag for select All as:

```
 <option value="-1">Select All</option>
```

This will pass -1 to your controller function. Where you can check like:

```
if (value.Equals(-1))
{
     //Your logic to select all records from database
}
```

Hope this helps.